# connection data source Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, odbc, oledb

How we can delete a second connection(ODBC) data source after adding
    a conntion OLEdb?

Thanks.

Comment: what is second connection?

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding and deleting connections to Crystal reports. You are adding datasources. If you can see 2 connections there is a table, stored proc, view or command, which is using the second one. Update the connection to the new one for all datasources